# Is there a way to use a variable for template html property *key* in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm looking for a way to use a variable for a template html property *key*. For example,

```
<path [attr.data-**<use-variable-here>**]="edge.id"></path>
```

Is there a way to do this in Angular 7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this via [@ViewChild](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-attributes-on-butt).

Template:

```html
<path #path></path>
```

Component:

```js
@ViewChild('path', {static:true}) path: ElementRef;

//... some lifecycle hook | method | callback
ngOnInit() {
  const customVariable = 'my-custom';
  this.path.nativeElement.setAttribute(`data-${customVariable}`, 'my-custom');
}
```

Check this stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-attributes-on-butt)